# How to create a timer in android that reset a counter variable into 0 every 5 second?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-manifest

i make an emergency application that will send a SMS to the 5 people when volume down key or menu key is pressed.
this is my code for detect a keypress when the activity launched:

```
package com.application.tpa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int ctrMenu=0,ctrkeyUp=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //startService(new Intent(main.this, PAservice.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {
            ctrkeyUp=0;
            ctrMenu++;
            if (ctrMenu==5)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the Menu button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ctrMenu=0;
            }
            //return true;
        }
        else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
            ctrMenu=0;
            ctrkeyUp++;
            if (ctrkeyUp==5)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the Volume Down button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
                ctrkeyUp=0;
            }
            //return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

has everyone know how to create timer (or whatever) in android to reset my counter variable into zero every 3 second?? so i can runs some procedure when a button is pressed 5 times before 3 seconds.. Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you can use the Timer using TimerTask:

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

               // add your stuff here
                }
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);
```

To cancel the timer you can use `timer.cancel();`

Comment: it works nicely suri.. many thanks for your help.. have a nice day suri.. :)

Comment: Same to you have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` classes.